# Error while starting tomcat server inside docker centos

Tags: tomcat, docker, centos, docker-compose

I am trying to start an apache server running inside centos inside a docker container. In my Dockerfile, to run the server, I have following command:

```
FROM centos:6
#(few commands)
CMD sleep 60 && sh /opt/liferay/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh  && tail -f /opt/liferay/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/logs/catalina.out
```

But I am getting following error for running startup.sh for apache.

```
: command not founday/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh: line 2:
: command not founday/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh: line 17:
: command not founday/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh: line 23:
'eb_1  | /opt/liferay/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'eb_1  | /opt/liferay/liferay/tomcat-6.0.32/bin/startup.sh: line 27: `case "`uname`" in
```

Here are first 30 lines of my startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Start Script for the CATALINA Server
#
# $Id: startup.sh 562770 2007-08-04 22:13:58Z markt $
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Better OS/400 detection: see Bugzilla 31132
os400=false
darwin=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the line numbers where you have errors (line 2, 17, 23, etc...).
It seems that they all happen when there is a new line.

Check your `startup.sh` file settings, it **should be LF** rather than CRLF. I did check the script with LF and it's working on centOS 6.

You can have a look at [Running Scripts in a Docker Container from Windows- CR or CRLF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/09/22/running-scripts-in-a-docker-container-from-windows-cr-or-crlf/) for more information if you're using windows to build you docker container.

Comment: Yes. It was some kind of line ending characters error. Resolved it by running dos2unix over all shell scripts. Thanks